# Getting a build error on android studio while using java cv

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, javacv

I am not able to get a successful gradle build in android studio which uses Java CV.
The error looks like this:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'
```

My build.gradle looks like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bytecoders.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.4.2'

}
```

update:
Got this fixed by not using the entire javacv-platform in dependencies.
I found that when we use entire javacv-platform all unnecessary dependencies for android development like Windows, OS X also get included in the grade causing redundant files.
So include only the dependencies needed for me, in this case a face recognition dependencies like:

- JavaCV arm
- OpenCV arm
- FFmpeg arm

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: add:  apply plugin: 'java'